# Find out what an installed app is doing in the background using adb

Tags: android, adb

Is there a way to find out using adb or any other tool, what activities (eg. like logcat) of an installed app on my phone?

eg. If I install a proxy on my PC and setup the phone with the proxy (like Charles Proxy) I can see all webtraffic of all apps.

eg. I want to find out what files WhatsApp is accessing or what activities it has active. What permissions is being triggered, what activity is invoking, etc

Comment: Are you working in Android Studio?

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff yeah, I have Android Studio installed. Basically I have a few apps on my phone and I would like to know what's doing. Eg. if I click a button, I want to see if it's accessing any files - like a task manager on Windows - I'm on macOS btw.

Comment: Have you tried logcat? It's pretty detailed as far as events are concerned. ADB is more of a system administration tool.

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff using logcat did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For those that comes next.

```
adb logcat | grep 'com.packagename'
```